# MySQL replication & logrotate

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication, logrotate

I'm using MySQL Master-Slave replication for backup purposes (for a few days).

Today after changing to `expire_logs_days = 3` on master and slave I got this message (from slave):

```
/etc/cron.daily/logrotate: 
/usr/bin/mysqladmin: refresh failed; error: 'Can't generate a unique log-filename mysqld-relay-bin.(1-999)'
error: error running shared postrotate script for '/var/log/mysql.log /var/log/mysql/mysql.log /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log '
run-parts: /etc/cron.daily/logrotate exited with return code 1
```

I tried to google what that message mean ("Can't generate...") but only error message definitions found instead of explanation.

Currently I've about 50 bin-log files on slave (`mysqld-relay-bin.000003` to `mysqld-relay.bin.000052`).

Comment: What version of mysql ???

Comment: mysqld  Ver 5.5.30-1.1-log for debian-linux-gnu on x86_64 ((Debian))

Comment: I'm seeing the same for mariadb :(

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the password set in `/etc/mysql/debian.cnf` for the `debian-sys-maint` user is the same for both the Master and the Slave, since the slave is an exact copy of the master, they have the same users table.

Answer (score -2):

This could happen if the opened files exceeded the mx open file limit set.
Here is how you can increase max file limit
http://duntuk.com/how-raise-ulimit-open-files-and-mysql-openfileslimit

Comment: From the Help Center, "Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."